# RecyclerView inside view-pager inside a scrollview

Tags: android

i have this layout >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="header_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/moods_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/mainwindow_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainwindow_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/view_border_top" />
</LinearLayout>
```

An d ViewPager Fragment have this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/net_rclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i want the

> header_content layout

to be scrolled out when the

> net_rclerview inside the view-pager fragment

is scrolled.
the problem is recyclerview is scrolling but the above content is not scrolling out of the view ,, is this possible to achieve and if there are any other options i can do ?

Comment: make RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); to your recyclerview

Comment: @NileshRathod no not working :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I just came across similar problem and after a lot of surfing I figured out that **issue was not with RecyclerView but with ViewPage**r. **ViewPager 's WrapContent property does not work** when put inside ScrollView. So a fixed height restrict RecyclerView to showUp full contents. Just Update ViewPager's OnMeasure Method as Follow:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    boolean canSwipe = true;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        View child = getChildAt(getCurrentItem());
        if (child != null) {
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void canSwipe(boolean canSwipe) {
        this.canSwipe = canSwipe;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.canSwipe) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.canSwipe) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

It worked for me. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: You are genius ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollingView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

and

make `RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`  to your  `recyclerview`

Comment: i forget to mention that all this code is inside a main viewpager : MainWindow  > Viewpager >ScrollView{ Content And View pager} -> RecylereView